# Android fullscreen VideoView maintain aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am wondering whether it is possible to have a video view that maintains aspect ratio and takes up the fullscreen of any android device **without stretching** and with **no black bars on the side**. I'm thinking this is not possible without multiple versions of the video itself. Just looking for confirmation. Right now I am simply making it full screen across the board for all devices by using video view alignment like so:

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/surface_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
</VideoView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're asking for is physically impossible.  If you want to maintain aspect ratio, that means you have to scale the width and height by the same percentage.  If that just happens to perfectly fit, you're fine.  If it doesn't, you have black bars or you have to break aspect ratio to fill it.  You'd need videos that perfectly fit to every screen size.  Most screens are 16:9 or 4:3, so if you have the video in both formats you'll fit most screens, but there will always be some outliers.